# iOS adhoc cannot install applications because the certificate for xxxx.com is not vaild in iOS7.1 beta2

Tags: ios, certificate, adhoc

I'm attempting to distribute an adhoc build to my tester.

In iOS7.1 Beta they are having trouble installing the app via a webpage.

In iOS7.1 beta2 safari warns that it cannot install applications because the certificate for xxxx.com is not valid.

In iOS7.0 and iOS6.x it works

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1 it's worked