# Continuous Integration with iOS 7.1 - can't install the product linked on the server

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, self-signed, xcode-bots

We've been running CI with Xcode 5.0 for some time with no issue. Now iOS 7.1 has been released it seems to install the products that the CI produces [you need to be on https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1) but it seems that self signed certs are ok.

I have switched to https (self-signed) which loads the bot page fine, but when you go to install the product from the link it says cannot connect to *server*

Trying to install it on http causes the error `Cannot install applications because the certificate for 'server' is not valid.`.

Do I have to get a proper certificate or am I doing something wrong with the self signed cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's the same problem although it needs to be signed with your own CA authority rather than just a self signed certificate.

For instructions on how to do this follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1#22367111).