# Can't install ipa generated by Xcode Server bot on the device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I've got my Xcode server setup on a mac mini. Downloading the .ipa from https://pandora.local/xcode/ using Itunes works just fine.

I tried installing it directly from the phone from safari. It installs a certificate but when I click install it gives an error, saying that it can't connect to the server.

[image]
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Continuous Integration with iOS 7.1 - can't install the product linked on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344596/continuous-integration-with-ios-7-1-cant-install-the-product-linked-on-the-se)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having a similar issue. I have an SSL certificate but the Install link fails :(

Comment: Just installed Xcode on the client's mac....

Answer (score 3):

For the mention issue, I got solved by going into iphone settings -> general - > About - > Scroll to the bottom , Click on Certificate Trust Settings -> trun on for Xcode Server Root Certificate Authority. See screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

had the exact same issue and it was a browser caching issue on Safari.

I went into Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> Website Data, then left swiped on my Xcode server website to reveal the Delete button and clicked on it for just that website.

The next time I browsed to the Xcode server in Safari and attempted to install a build, I received the prompt to install the OTA certificate and when accepted done that I could install applications.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same, deleting the Website Data for my xcode server, but that did not actually work for me.

See my answer at [Xcode bot install link request time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336185/xcode-bot-install-link-request-time-out?nah=1#28859132) for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the answer [offical description](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204477),

In iOS 10.3 and later, when you manually install a profile that contains a certificate payload, that certificate isn't automatically trusted for SSL.

You must manually turn on trust for SSL when you install a profile that is sent to you via email or downloaded from a website.
If you want to turn on SSL trust for that certificate, go to Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings. Under "Enable full trust for root certificates," turn on trust for the certificate.
Apple recommends deploying certificates via Apple Configurator or Mobile Device Management (MDM). Certificate payloads installed with Configurator, MDM, or as part of an MDM enrollment profile are automatically trusted for SSL.