# iOS 7.1 OTA SSL error

Tags: ssl, plist, ipa, ota, ios7.1

I´m trying to solve this new problem for internal deployment and testing.
I was successful creating an Internal CA certificate, and a SSL one with it. The host is a local IIS referenced as hostname.domain. I installed the CA certificate on the host and configured the HTTPS for the site (hostname.domain) with the SSL certificate. I tested on MacOS Safari client and it could not verified the site until I installed the CA certificate in the keychain. This means that SSL Certificate and CA are working correctly for the host name…
Then I e-mailed me the CA certificate and installed in my ipad. It is showed as a profile with one certificate, Trusted.
Unfortunately Ipad´s Safari keeps telling me that cannot verify the identity of the hostname.domain, and if I continue to the page accepting it, the OTA download fails with the message “Cannot connect to hostname.domain”

Any idea of what is missing?
Thanks.

Comment: After trying anything possible type of CAs, SelfSigned Certs... The problem was that one of my colleagues have changed the device's date to some in the past...
So the certificate was not valid for safari
I've changed back the date to today and started working.

Comment: Pl. see this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to fix this is by creating a signed certificate that is issued by a Certificate Authority that you also create for your organization. The specifics can be found on this particular answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22367111/71079

This command line application will help you set this up: https://github.com/deckarep/EasyCert/releases