# Upgraded Adhoc app deployment doesn't work on iOS previous to 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, distribution, adhoc

I had trouble with installing -deployed adhoc- development app before upgrading to iOS 7.1 and XCode 5.1
XCode 5.0 wasn't recognizing iPhones with iOS 7.1.
We upgraded and everything seems fine until we deployed as adhoc distribution.
I followed solution at [Enterprise app deployment doesnt work on ios 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1) and it greatly worked for installing the app in iphones with ios 7.1

But, now iphones with ios 7.0x can't install the app.
Results that some of our boss' bosses hadn't upgraded and don't want to, and desires backwards compatibility.

The app starts downloading but stops in the middle, the icon is completely grayed out and the app doesn't open.

Looking for alternatives, we are trying to acquire another macbook with previous system but it had been very hard to obtain our current resources.
We started implementing in the html page a script for recognizing the device, using user-agent variable, we plan to use this script to choose different plist files for iOS version 7.1 or previous. We expect it works as soon as we obtain the ipa in the newer macbook, as soon as we get it...

I wish for an easier solution that allows compatibility with newer versions and let us avoid project 'branch'ification.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are yours deployment target set to ios 7.0?

Comment: so, I set it to 7.1. It works fine with 7.1 but no with 7.0. Should I have to compile two versions?

Comment: To run app on ios 7.0 you should have deployment target at least 7.0