# OTA (Over the air) IOS 7.1 after change http-https still cannot connect server?

Tags: ios, ota

For iOS 7.1, when you try to do an OTA install which has an http link to the .plist file, you will get this error:
‘Cannot install applications because the certificate for com.test.com is not valid’ then
I have a found ios 7.1 cannot use http anymore.Need to change http to **https**

like example

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://www.test.com/OTA_App_Name.plist
```

to

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://www.test.com/OTA_App_Name.plist
```

After i change it still got error "unable to connect www.test.com".I have check all my plist details is correct link.Any Idea?Did i need to set https certificate also?How?

Comment: could the certificate be a self signed one?

Comment: duplicate of this. here's your answer: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1/20276908#20276908

Comment: did the same thing and getting the same problem. Any Luck?

Answer (score 0):

iOS requires a certificate it can verify. Maybe you are using a self-sign certificates, these don't work. You can, however, use wildcard certificates, if that helps you in any way.

Answer (score -1):

We just had this same issue recently.  You have to change the link as you did, but you must also resave the plist.  When you archive and distribute for ad/hoc enterprise, you have to enter the app url.  enter `https://www.test.com/OTA_App_Name.ipa`.  That fixed it for us, no cert magic.