# iOS Enterprise app hosting with Azure Websites and similar

Tags: ios, iphone, azure, ssl, https

We intend to distribute a mobile app to a customer who is a retail wholesaler with franchisee/store owners. Platforms supported will be Android and iOS.
For the iOS distribution we prefer that the app is distributed using the iOS enterprise program rather than to the retail app store.
One of the restrictions which I have read about (having never "published" an enterprise iOS app in the past) is that the link to download the IPA or .plist file should be provided via HTTPS/SSL.
This means that the serving URL must have an SSL cert bound to it and not merely a self signed cert.
Apparently this restriction is relatively new (perhaps iOS 8 or 9)

I've noticed that Azure provide so-called wildcard SSL certs for subdomains of their Azure Website or Azure Web Services offerings.
Would such a wildcard SSL certificate be adequate to address the minimal requirements for the iOS device to validate the download of the app ?
Obviously, what I am thinking here is that we host the link to latest app download from a Azure web app/web site.
The app would obviously have been built with the correct provisioning profile and app id required for enterprise deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an answer in this post wildcard ssl certificates are allowed:

[OTA (Over the air) IOS 7.1 after change http-https still cannot connect server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505206/ota-over-the-air-ios-7-1-after-change-http-https-still-cannot-connect-server)

However, please note that distributing enterprise provisioned iOS applications to persons outside of your company violates your agreement with Apple. If Apple finds out that you're distributing applications to people outside of your company using your enterprise account, they can ban your account.

Comment: Having looked into this in more detail it looks like the Apple iOS B2B programme coupled with volume purchase program (for our business "customers") is the way to go. However, I cannot quite understand what the pricing structure is for that or if it works along the lines that you sign up with the regular iOS developer programme and the pre-purchased vouchers and AppID for the end customer is used to allow the developer business to push an IP via iTunesConnect to the recipient business's private App store ?