# Error when distributing an IPA over the air with dropbox - iOS 7.1

Tags: plist, dropbox, ipa, ios7.1, ota

As Apple requested to use https instead of http for distributing the IPAs over the air, I tried to use dropbox. I followed this solution [Enterprise app deployment doesn't work on iOS 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1) but I'm getting this error:

> "Cannot connect to dl.dropboxusercontent.com"

when trying to install the plist through this link: `<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/56ny312cwdacho7/xxxxx.plist> Install </a>`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @nano....please let us know the steps to Distributing an IPA over the air with dropbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. Firstly I tried putting all of my files in the public folder of my dropbox account. It still didn't work but I noticed with modifying my plist file I had overwritten the closing "</string>" XML tag for the ipa file itself. Once I added that back in it all worked. So whether it would have worked without moving to the public folder I do not know. I haven't tried because I have the result I desire for my users.

Comment: Right. The problem was in the title of the plist file. I was using a strange character. After removing it, it worked using dropbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

**NOTE** : Shared links don’t render HTML content in a web browser

Refer https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download

Check question

> How to force render a file in a browser

---

**EDIT** : Reason is you will need to change link url and reupload it :

- replace `www.dropbox.com` with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com in`all links
- `Reupload` by making changes in link which are in  `html` and `plist` file again.

Thats it. Enjoy

---

**TOTAL SOLUTION**

`Needed file` for `distribution` using `example link` are given below :

- Build your app from xcode using Build and Archive option. `Upload` your `ipa file` to `Dropbox`. And `get` public `link` for the `ipa`.

**Note** : replace `www.dropbox.com` with `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` in the `link`.

- Download the [manifest.plist](https://gist.github.com/palaniraja/1051160) - `edit` the line #14 with the public `link` of your `ipa` . `Modify` other keys as well (`bundle-identifier, bundle-version, title`) .
- `Upload` the modified `manifest.plist` to `Dropbox` and `get` its `public link`.
- Download the [index.html](https://gist.github.com/palaniraja/1051163) - `edit url param` at line #8 with public `link` of `your manifest.plist`

**Hosting using Github**. How that can be achieved is explained in following steps

1. Create a new project.
2. Add index.html as we will be hosting a site in Github Pages. Note
   html file with other name will not be valid as it should always be
   with index name.
3. Now go to project settings. Traverse through Github Pages
4. Under source tab select master-branch and click on save
5. Traverse back Github Pages you will see site will be published

[image]

Now you have Download link like https://paresh-navadiya.github.io/install.html/

---

**Refer** [How to distribute using DropBox by @
oldman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22325916/1106035) and [Distribute your iPhone/iPad adhoc builds Over The Air using DropBox](http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.in/2011/06/distribute-your-iphoneipad-adhoc-builds.html)

It working 100% percent.

Have a nice day to all :)

Comment: How did you find the link dl.dropboxusercontent.com for dropbox.com?

Comment: @jailani all you have to do is replace www.dropbox.com in the URL with dl.dropboxusercontent.com

Comment: I don't know why ? but in my case it's downloading `index.html` file  :(

Comment: @Jack I have updated my answer with solution to downloading link

Comment: @paresh will adding github, dropbox link with major downloads cause problem with apple guidelines?.. i saw many link on dropbox not works due to huge traffic.(limited calls only)

Comment: @Jack According to apple guidelines, OTA download link should be https or secured. Dropbox download link is secured hence apple should not have any problem.

Comment: THANK YOU.  None of the many guides I found for this process mentioned dl.dropboxusercontent.com .... that's the only thing I had to change to get it working!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue with dropbox few days back, saying **cannot connect to dl.dropboxusercontent.com**, what I did is **deleting the sharable link which I created earlier** and **created a new sharable link for both plist and ipa files**. And I updated these links in plist and html page. I don't know what was wrong with my old sharable links. Hope this answer might be helpful for someone.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in a similar reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22678471/808581), if the PLIST file is malformed, this error will appear.

In my case, I forgot the fact that the ampersand ("&") charcater is forbidden in XML, and the name of my app contained "&" in it, so I had to replace the `&` with `&amp;` in the  containing the name and everything worked.