# How to Distribute .Ipa Using Dropbox in iOS

Tags: ios, distribution

I want to distribute my app to testers using dropbox.The links I followed were

1. http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.in/2011/06/distribute-your-iphoneipad-adhoc-builds.html
2. [Error when distributing an IPA over the air with dropbox - iOS 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658987/error-when-distributing-an-ipa-over-the-air-with-dropbox-ios-7-1)

Finally I created Html and when I click on that it shows an alert “dropbox.com would to to install app”. But when I click on that nothing happening instead of installing…

What might be the chances of failure(My device IPAD2, OS-8.1.3 )

Console log Info:http://pastebin.com/3WbgjT6Q

Thank you.

Comment: Can you upload your console logs from your device when you try to install the via the link?

Comment: @GlenT Im not getting any consloe Logs

Comment: Oh not your regular logs, but rather here https://wiki.appcelerator.org/download/attachments/29004939/Xcode6DeviceConsole.png?version=1&modificationDate=1409257832000&api=v2 (from https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Native+iOS+Debugging+and+Testing+Tools )

Comment: These r the logs  http://pastebin.com/3WbgjT6Q

Comment: Can you capture only the logs that occur after attempting an install?

Comment: After clicking Install in the alert http://pastebin.com/BHNQ3Dy1

Comment: This looks like the relevant line "Mar  4 13:25:17 iPad2 itunesstored[2345] <Warning>: LoadExternalDownloadManifestOperation: Ignore manifest download, already have bundleID: com.Mybundleid.main". Why this is not downloading I'm not sure.

Comment: Shall i need to install provsining profile seperately .......

Comment: You shouldn't need to install the provisioning profile separately. Sorry to ask another thing but can you share a link to your dropbox files. I.e. plist, html?

Comment: Have you tried to open https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4knzyo7ngzhetkg/OrderEm.html on a phone? This seems to work for me (except I get provisioning profile errors as I am not in the device list)

Comment: I tried, its just shown up alert to install, If i click Install nothing happens

Comment: check the home screen, you should see the app icon appear and start downloading.

Comment: No it's Not installing, Same logs r cmng in the console. I think I'm missing some where, don't know where it is

Comment: It may be an Ios 8 Issue, I have to try in older devices

Comment: It starts downloading for me on iOS8...

Comment: How, Your device id is not there na

Comment: I know it failed at the end with the following errors:
Mar  4 22:12:49 GT6 installd[17387] <Error>: 0x100584000 -[MIInstallableBundle _installEmbeddedProfileInBundle:]: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012 (Unsupported device)

Comment: Even for me Down load is not at all started, Have u changed any thing in HTML files

Comment: Only the link it has to use the 'dl.dropboxusercontent.com' domain, not dropbox.com. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Finally its got wrkng with the Update of bundleid, I don'y know whats the reason behind it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772664/enterprise-app-update-distribution-on-ios-8  any way  Thank you so much for u r support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use app loader to distribute beta version to your testers. It is very simple and fast. I am using it after closed testflight .

Comment: Howmuch it will take to approve, I think its same as real Appstore process, but Can i test immediately with that..

Comment: @sivakrishnaperla, sure, just move to Crashlytics Beta or other test service.

Comment: Ya, I was just tested Crashlytics,

Comment: Yes you can test it immediately with that.There is no need to approve from app store. Just select .ipa and send link to testers.

Comment: @RaviGautam Let me know the total process by using APP loader