# Apple Enterprise Development Program

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I just purchased the Apple Enterprise Development Program. I am the only developer within my company. I will be the only one developing and distributing the apps. Now the app is developed and ready in Xcode.

How to distribute apps to my company employees? I have gone through the Apple tutorials but they are very confusing and have too much information in them that I don't understand.

All company employees have company issued iPhones.

Comment: Check [Distribute your iPhone/iPad adhoc builds Over The Air using Dropbox](http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.in/2011/06/distribute-your-iphoneipad-adhoc-builds.html)

Comment: Also check [Distributing an IPA over the air with dropbox - iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25302392/1106035)

Comment: Use Testflight Application which I highly recommend!

Comment: @PareshNavadiya thank you thank you for answering. I am very confused here. What is the proper way to distributing apps to employee iPhones. Can send them an email or a message. if so how. again thank you!!!

Comment: You can send them  app downloadable link (dropbox's content)  through email

Comment: if I update my app how can the users get a update saying a version of the app is available. Like we get one for apps on the app store.

Comment: Use a webservice call which has app version and app download link  which gets modified when there is change. Now you check app version every day once and if there is change notify user with popup that new version is available and when user clicks update button then redirect it to safari where user downloads it. Also in settings add update so user don't have wait a day.

Comment: should I check the app version every day through the app. Meaning would the code for checking the version be within my app? I have my own API which I created using node.js mongoDB and express.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88694/discussion-between-paresh-navadiya-and-user2190986).

Answer (score 0):

you can upload you ipa to "Development iOS Apps Wireless Installation" site.

http://www.diawi.com

and email them installation url. When one click this url your app will be installed into his/her iPhone.iPad.

Note: when you update your app. you have to upload a new ipa and give them a new link.

Comment: thank you for the answer. What if I update my app. would I have to upload a new ipa and give them a new link?