# iOS 7.1.1 OTA Distribution - Connection failed

Tags: ios, iphone, plist, ota

I've a problem with distributing my iOS App on my iPhone 5c with installed iOS 7.1.1 over-the-air.
I followed [this](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/) instruction to get rid of the certificate-problems. My plist looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>assets</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software-package</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>http://192.168.1.156/App.ipa</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>display-image</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>http://192.168.1.156/icon.png</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>full-size-image</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>http://192.168.1.156/icon@2x.png</string>
            </dict>
        </array>

        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
            <string>de.app.bundle</string>
            <key>bundle-version</key>
            <string>1.0.0</string>
            <key>kind</key>
            <string>software</string>
            <key>subtitle</key>
            <string>for iOS</string>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>AppTitle</string>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I'm delivering the plist over nginx 1.7.0 on windows 7 and the mimetype for plist is application/xml.

The itms-services url opened in iOS looks like so:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://192.168.1.156/install.plist">Install App</a>
```

When I try to open this link in safari I get a message "Connection to 192.168.1.156 failed". But I cannot see any request in my nginx access logs. So I think that there must be a problem with my link to the plist or with iOS itself. I tried to url-encode the content of the url parameter with same result.

Does anybody have any idea what's going wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be the issue related to SSL.In your .plist file you specified

```
http://192.168.1.156/App.ipa
```

and in manifest url it is  `https://192.168.1.156/install.plist`. So your url where the ipa file reside may not have a valid SSL certificate.
See the discussion : [Enterprise app deployment doesn't work on iOS 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1/22367111#22367111)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've installed the certificates one more time and now the plist is delivered from the nginx. In Xcode organizer Console I get this error now: "Could not load download manifest with underlying error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=2 "Verbindung mit iTunes Store nicht möglich" UserInfo=0x16dd3350 {NSLocalizedDescription=Verbindung mit iTunes Store nicht möglich}"