# iOS ota distribution SSErrorDomain Code=2

Tags: ios, ota

In addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603243/ios-7-1-1-ota-distribution-connection-failed/23604427#23604427) post I've a new problem installing my app on my iOS 7.1.1 device over-the-air. I'm getting this error in xcode organizer:

```
 itunesstored[102] <Warning>: Could not load download manifest with underlying error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=2 "Verbindung mit iTunes Store nicht möglich" UserInfo=0x16ec5030 {NSLocalizedDescription=Verbindung mit iTunes Store nicht möglich}
```

Could it be a problem with the self signed certificate in general?

Comment: Then please un-accept the answer in your previous question, and edit it, instead of opening a new one as a follow-up -- possible duplicate of [iOS 7.1.1 OTA Distribution - Connection failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603243/ios-7-1-1-ota-distribution-connection-failed)

Comment: it is the right answer for the question in my previous post. Now I have a new question to the same task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with self signed certificate. The problem was that the plist file was wrong. The ending `</plist>` was missing. Now I can install the app with self signed certificate over the air (ota).