# Is it possible to distribute iOS app "in house" without Enterprise program?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program, in-house-distribution

I know questions like this one have been asked over and over again but I couldn't find an answer that goes straight to the point.

I have seen [guides](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/) that seems to allow you to distribute your app OTA without having to be part of the Enterprise program.

I also have seen some tricks where, if you don't have a SSL certificate in your hosting, you still can use dropbox to configure your "links". ([Enterprise app deployment doesn't work on iOS 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1))

In summary I have used dropbox as it was indicated in one of the answers I found before and it totally worked. The problem is that I tried to test it in a different device and it didn't work (typical message

> **Unable to Download App**. xxxx could not be installed at this time.

I'm signing the app using a **distribution certificate** and I'm using a **provisioning profile for distribution**:

I know it can sound pretty obvious that all that is meant to work only for the AppStore or ad-hoc distribution (this last one requires to collect all devices UDID and it's not what i'm looking for).

I would like to know if it is definitely possible or not to distribute my apps "in-house" without having to be part of the Enterprise program. If true... what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: testflight? it support up to 1000 users

Comment: But to use TestFlight I cannot create a build using a distribution profile. If I do it i get the message: 'Invalid Profile: does not contain provisioned devices, are you sure this is not a developer profile?'.
The only way would be an ad-hoc but to do so I have to include the provisioned devices, something I would like to avoid (if I can)

Answer (score 0):

Note: the guide you link to is *not* for in-house app distribution. That blog post is about ad-hoc distribution without using iTunes. It's not about not having to provision your devices or getting around paying for the Enterprise program.

It is possible, but it still requires the business to spend some money.

If the business is enrolled in the [Volume Purchase Program](https://vpp.itunes.apple.com/us/store) then you can identify them as the authorized purchaser of your [Business 2 Business app](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/) when you submit it to the App Store. Regular customers won't see it.

Unfortunately, Apple does not say up front how much it costs a business to enroll in the Volume Purchase Program (I'm guessing that it varies) so I don't know if it's cheaper than the Enterprise Program.