# Unable to download iOS enterprise app from server

Tags: ios, cordova, enterprise

I am trying to build an iOS enterprise mobile application using PhoneGap. But facing "Connection Invalid error". Provisioning profile, App ID and Certificate are mapped correctly.

Please find the error log :

```
<Notice>: (Error) error event: (<OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x3c46e7dc> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x3c46e9bc> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}>)
```

Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Rakesh Kalwa.

Comment: *Please* edit your question and format it properly. No one would want to read this unformatted pile of text. Also add some more detail to your question. Questions asking help for debug or just saying: "Why isn't this code working?" are off-topic in this website.

Comment: which version of iOS you are using?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when i upgraded from iOS 7 to 7.1. It is because of,starting from iOS 7.1 all the OTA IPA installations needs to be in HTTPS and it will throw error when we are using HTTP. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1) SO answers, to know more about the alternative way to get OTA installation of IPA.

Comment: Hi Currently we are using HTTPS only, We have successfully ported first application in our company server and able to download. This is the second application on same server but got the above error. Please help me in this issue.

Comment: Did you check required profile are installed in device? Also let me know which verison of IOS and some info about webserver?

Comment: We are using SOAP services. IOS version is 7.1, All the required certificates are installed in device. Please let me know if you need more info.