# Error while distributing app on air using dropbox

Tags: ios, deployment, air, plist, dropbox

I am using Enterprise certificate to distribute on air using dropbox following this link: http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air

1. While creating plist I used a dummy application URL and title i.e.
   https.....ipa, AppName resp.
2. Both ipa and plist Uploaded on dropbox
3. Used shared link of plist from dropbox and mention on HTML document
4. I used HTML webpage/document shared link (replacing www.dropbox.com by dl.dropboxusercontent.com).

But unable to download app.

While downloading I am getting the error: `Unable to download app. "AppName" can not be downloaded at this time.`

Console message:

```
BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: networkd apsd itunesstored 
 <Error>: FAILURE: Failed to open property list at file:///private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist for reading. (The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory)
 <Notice>: WiFi:[428491987.594512]: Client itunesstored set type to normal application
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1

Comment: I checked that and following the same steps. I think problem is with my 'application URL' which I mentioned while 'saving for Enterprise distribution'. This URL can be any arbitrary or any actual URL where I need to keep this ipa at some local server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url given during the "Save for Enterprise Distribution"  process is the url that gets saved in the `.plist`. That url should be the location of the `.ipa` file. 
Then the link to download your app is like this `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=<LINK_TO_PLIST>`  Then the `.plist` directs the user to the `.ipa` url saved in the `.plist`.  The link example was taken from a working implementation of OTA distribution that I did for iOS 7.1 devices a couple of months ago.

Comment: I just want to point out for anyone also using DropBox method, DropBox seems to append ?dl=0 to the end of the plist URL, so something like https://dl.dropbox.com/s/afeaeaxa/appPlist.plist?dl=0, I had to remove the "?dl=0" part before it started working, otherwise, the download webpage just doesn't show the "do you want to install app" alert message.