# App installation failed: Unknown Error Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My app runs fine in the simulator, but when I try to install it on my iPhone it says

> App installation failed: An unknown error has occurred.

I opened my device logs and got this:

> FAILURE: Failed to open property list at
>   file:///private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd/overrides.plist
>   for reading. (The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or
>   directory)

Comment: So what is your question?. have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056585/error-while-distributing-app-on-air-using-dropbox

Answer (score 1):

try it :

Xcode-> Preferences->Locations->Derived Data-> Delete it...
It will clean your project, Try to restart your device. Then build the app on the device.