# Enterprise build is not installing via server but can be installed by dropbox

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, itunes

I am trying to install enterprise app from my server but it is not installing , safari gives error "cannot connect to ", however when i look into device console it says "Could not load download manifest with underlying error: Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=2 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"" , I tried a lot most of available solution but can't find proper solution  .

Also when i upload same files (plist and ipa) to dropbox and tried to install via dropbox , app is successfully getting installed .

Please help , what  could be problem ,while loading from server .

Comment: In your server the manifest.plist and .ipa are correct? For on-air distribution of your app you **needs HTTPS** connection! 
experience becomes more quickly with Dropbox, you can take the link of the manifest and put it in an href to download it from a website.

Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. You need HTTPS connection with SSL certificate. Better you go with dropbox or in easiest way go with **DIAWI**. Just upload app with profile and share your link.