# sending .ipa file via url to install

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, ios-provisioning

I have gone through dozens of articles, stackoverflow questions and sites, my only requirement is to send .ipa file through url where client could check it in safari and install.

1. does not want third party installation, I've got my own server
2. my server is not having ssl that means it can be sent only http not https. please dont ask me to have ssl.
3. could able to install in any ios device, udid is not added to enterprise certificate.

My problem is when I am keeping these 3 file that are a) index.html. b)manifest.plist. and c).ipa file in server and trying to install in device, I am getting an pop up message saying that "certificate is not valid." Please help.

Comment: did you try using https://www.diawi.com/?
did you generate your ipa using ad-hoc provisioning profile?

Answer (score 1):

Hope the link below helps you out.
http://readwrite.com/2010/12/16/apple-best-kept-secret-how-to-do-ad-hoc-installs

But i dont think Apple allows you to distribute using http. Https is a mandatory for the URL that the user uses to download. So until you get a https i dont see that issue being solved

Answer (score 0):

1. Your own server should be fine.  As long as your .plist and .ipa are both accessible on the network to which the iPhone is connected.
2. Unfortunately, starting with iOS 7.1, app installs must be accessible over SSL (https).
3. The only way to do this is with an enterprise distribution profile.  You will need to have an enterprise account to do this, which will require a company's EIN.  So you can't do this as an individual developer.  (https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/)

You are seeing the error because of the lack of a valid SSL certificate on your server.  iOS is swapping your http:// link in your plist with https:// (see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20276908/3708242), which as you said does not have ssl enabled.

Bottom line, you'll need to get a server with SSL to host the files.  Also, if you don't want / can't manage the UDIDs for the devices, you will need to get yourself an enterprise account so you can create an enterprise distribution profile to use to build your app.

Answer (score 0):

There are online tools that simplify this process of sharing, for example https://abbashare.com or https://diawi.com
Create an ipa file from xcode with adhoc or inhouse profile, and upload this file on these site.
I prefer abbashare because save file on your dropbox and you can delete it whenever you want